# Calculate properties of a projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-varieties

I'm confused as to how to calculate certain properties of a given projective curve (e.g. multiplicities & tangent lines at a singular point) and how to think about these. I've read that multiplicities & tangent lines are local properties, and that we can calculate them by dehomogenizing the curve, but I don't really understand why.

For example, say that we want to calculate multiplicities and tangent lines of a projective curve $C$ defined by a polynomial $F(X,Y,Z)$ at a singular point $x = [a : b : 1] \in \mathbb P^2$. As far as I  understand, we can dehomogenize $F$ as $F_*(X,Y) = F(X,Y,1)$, calculate the multiplicity $m_{(a,b)}(F_*)$ and tangent lines $L_1, \dots, L_n$ (in $\mathbb A^2$), and then homogenize these tangent lines to acquire the tangent lines in projective space.

I'm having a hard time phrasing my question since I don't feel like I understand these concepts, but in summary, I'm confused as to why we can simply calculate the properties in affine space and then homogenize.

Thanks!

Comment: The idea is that local information and local properties at a point don't care about what open neighborhood of that point they're calculated from. So if you believe that these are local properties, there's your answer. If you're looking for proof that these properties are local, could you post your definitions so answerers make sure their proofs are appropriate to your setting?